# Adding surface in symbology QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, expression, surface

I would like the symbols to show the total area of ​​each type of land use.
I tried to do it but I can't separate them.

[image]

[image: Surface by symbol]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter in the aggregate expression IF your symbol_label is a value that can be obtained from your attribute.There is an easy way to do this, but it iss in PR limbo.

Such as `sum($area,filter:="attribute"=@symbol_label)`

Also be caution if you want to multiply this value and concat the string. The concat operator has precedence over math operators.